# iCloud/CloudKit Dashboard Issues with Telemetry, Logs, Usage Display, Subscriptions, Notifications

Tags: icloud, cloudkit

Bad things happening on iCloud/Cloudkit Dashboard for my app's container right now. Below is a summary of the issues I am having:

Issue 1: Login to the Cloudkit Dashboard. Select iCloud.com.mycompany.myapp container. Select Production>Telemetry. Error Popup: "Unable to Load Telemetry Data. Please file a Radar and include the current URL"

Issue 2: Select Logs from top Dropdown. Select Historical. Tap Search Logs. Error: "Error Loading Logs. The Logs could not be queried. Please try again later."

Issue 3: Select Usage from top Dropdown. There is absolutely no usage in Monthly or Daily (which is inaccurate)

Issue 4: Select Data from top Dropdown. Select Subscriptions. Hit Fetch Subscriptions button. "There are no subscriptions in this database" displays (which is inaccurate).

Issue 5: Change notifications are not being sent for subscriptions that, when queried for within the app, DO exist.

Are these problems just something that I am experiencing, or are other people having similar issues with iCloud/Cloudkit? Is this related to the new UI? Is there anything I can try to do to debug or fix these issues or is this something that is simply out of my control?

Comment: could you solve this?

Comment: It was a temporary issue and resolved after a certain amount of time, though I don't remember how long. Maybe less than two days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds to me like something unique to your account, or potentially a temporary degradation of service on Apple's part.

I would contact [Developer Technical Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact) and see if they can help.

Comment: They don't help. They redirect you to the feedback assistant in which, if lucky they will look it in a few months.

Answer (score 0):

There is an all new design for the dfashboard.  Try it again and see if your issue was the transformation to this new design.

Comment: My issue has been since the new design.